# Delete a variable or object from the page using javascript

Tags: javascript

I used delete keyword to delete a variable but it doesn't seem to work....

```
var txt = "Some text";
alert(txt); //Output - Some text
delete txt;
alert(txt); //SAME OUTPUT - Some text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delete` is used to delete *properties*, not variables. That is, it is used to remove a property from an object.

According to [MDN's explanation of `delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete), "You can use the delete operator to delete variables declared implicitly but not those declared with the var or the function statement."

So the behaviour you've described is correct.

Comment: To delete a variable, you have to do `txt = undefeind`.

Comment: @Derek: That doesn't delete a variable, it simply assigns it the "value" `undefined`. It does, however, allow what the variable previously referenced to be garbage collected _unless_ there are other references to it (in other variables). There _is_ a difference between a variable or property that doesn't exist and a variable or property that exists but has the "value" `undefined`.

Comment: So that's mean you can't really delete a variable? Once you declared a variable and that's it, it will not be able to be deleted?

Comment: You don't really need to delete variables: setting them to `undefined` will let the browser free up the memory because the thing the variable referenced can disappear - but it's like emptying a box: the box itself doesn't vanish into thin air.

Comment: `delete window.txt` works _if_ you created it with `window.txt = ...` in the first place, but not if created with `var`. And of course `window` only applies to global variables. It's good practice for unrelated reasons to avoid (too many) globals, so if you use a namespacing scheme your "variables" would actually be properties of your namespace object so you cold delete them.